# Same variable name in different module files return always the last one

Tags: module, lua

I wrote two `lua` modules with the the same variable name `chapter` in each one of them, but with different strings. In the main code, when I try to print all the chapters, i.e. I would get the chapters from the different modules and printed them all, only the last loaded modules get its chapters printed.

How do I access the chapters variables in each module in the main code? Here's the MWE:

**First module:**

```
local modOne = {}

Chapter = {}
    Chapter[1] = {chapNum = 1}
        Chapter[1][1] = "This is the first verse of the modOne"
        Chapter[1][2] = "This is the second verse of the modOne"
    Chapter[2] = {chapNum = 2}
        Chapter[2][1] = "This is the third verse of the modOne"
        Chapter[2][2] = "This is the fourth verse of the modOne"

return modOne
```

**Second module:**

```
local modTwo = {}

Chapter = {}
    Chapter[1] = {chapNum = 1}
        Chapter[1][1] = "This is the first verse of the modTwo"
        Chapter[1][2] = "This is the second verse of the modTwo"
    Chapter[2] = {chapNum = 2}
        Chapter[2][1] = "This is the third verse of the modTwo"
        Chapter[2][2] = "This is the fourth verse of the modTwo"

return modTwo
```

**Main code:**

```
oneModule = require('modOne')
twoModule = require('modTwo')

for i = 1, #Chapter do
    for j = 1, #Chapter[i] do
        print(Chapter[i][j])
    end
end
```

The code reads always the `Chapter` variable that is in the last module loaded, but I would like to choose which `Chapter` I want to print. I tried to access the `Chapter` variable in each module by `oneModule.Chapter[1][1]` or `twoModule.Chapter[2][1]` for example, but it returns an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example modules you provide are coded so that nothing is added to the table that is returned.

This results in `Chapter` being a global variable, which is created by the first module and then changed by the second.

To correct this the modules should be written like:

#### modOne:

```
local modOne = {
    Chapter = {
        [1] = {
            chapNum = 1,
            [1] = "This is the first verse of the modOne",
            [2] = "This is the second verse of the modOne",
        },
        [2] = {
            chapNum = 2,
            [1] = "This is the third verse of the modOne",
            [2] = "This is the fourth verse of the modOne",
        }
    }
}
return modOne
```

#### modTwo:

```
local modTwo = {
    Chapter = {
        [1] = {
            chapNum = 1,
            [1] = "This is the first verse of the modTwo",
            [2] = "This is the second verse of the modTwo",
        },
        [2] = {
            chapNum = 2,
            [1] = "This is the third verse of the modTwo",
            [2] = "This is the fourth verse of the modTwo",
        }
    }
}
return modTwo
```

#### Main Code:

```
oneModule = require('modOne')
twoModule = require('modTwo')

for i = 1, #oneModule.Chapter do
    for j = 1, #oneModule.Chapter[i] do
        print(oneModule.Chapter[i][j])
    end
end
for i = 1, #twoModule.Chapter do
    for j = 1, #twoModule.Chapter[i] do
        print(twoModule.Chapter[i][j])
    end
end
```

You could also simply be sure to put `modOne.Chapter` when you define `Chapter` in the module and everywhere you use it within the module.

Comment: Thank you very much! Don't forget the comma to separate the `Chapter` entries.